# Get userinput value out of dialog function

Tags: android

I want to get a simple String out of that dialog function into the variable "name".
First AS tells me this: "Variable 'name' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final". If i make it final it tells me a final value cannot be changed. I found some similar questions and tutorials already but they just display the user input with a toast or else. I need the value out of  there. This might be something elementary, but at the moment i can't get any further..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView eventNameETMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
    String name;

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View adView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_event, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder eventNameAB = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
            eventNameAB.setView(adView);
            final EditText eventNameET = (EditText)adView.findViewById(R.id.eventNameET);

            eventNameAB.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    name = eventNameET.getText().toString();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = eventNameAB.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: move your String "name" outside of the function onCreate to make it a class member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to declare a class-level variable like so:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private String mName = null;
```

then later

```
mName = eventNameET.getText().toString();
```

Then access the variable wherever else you need it.

Comment: and what if u need variable to be local?

Comment: Can you provide some info on what you want to do with it? It seems like the thing to understand is that you're accessing `name` at a different time, right? So inside of other methods, such as `onCreate` or the outer `onClick`, it's not going to be useful to access the name because those events will have already finished processing by the time the button would be pressed on the AlertDialog. If you're showing it on the screen, you'll want to access the TextView that will show it and call `myTextView.setText(name)` from inside of the onClick method. With more info, I can be more helpful.

Comment: yes, you are correct !, I also guess that is the case of the OP's question but however I was just saying that your answer is the not the only solution specially in cases that you want the variable to be a local var [not caring about what is used for]

Comment: Absolutely. I just said it's the easiest way to deal with it, and, I think, the clearest. If you need it to be local, a simple `String` isn't the best option. You would probably want some kind of wrapper class that can hold an instance of String. You'd declare and instantiate a `final` instance of this class locally and then in `onClick`, call `myClass.setName(name)`. Then call `getName()` wherever else you need it locally. As I said, this is more work than simply moving the declaration to the class level, but also valid.

Comment: there is a more easy way [Android Studio suggests it to you!], in case if you want it to be local, I added it as an answer blew [yes the down-voted answer :D]

Comment: I am writng a who pays what app. And the string from the dialog will be my event name. like "birthdayparty". Both answers work for me. Thank you!